# Using maven-release-plugin to tag and commit to non-origin

Tags: git, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

When I do a release of my project, I want to share the source with a wider group of people than I normally do during development.  The code is shared via a Git repository.  To do this, I have used the following:

- remote public repository - released code is pushed here, every week or so (http://example.com/public)
- remote private repository - non-release code is pushed here, more than daily (http://example.com/private)

In my local git repository, I have the following remotes defined:

```
origin  http://example.com/private
public  http://example.com/public
```

I am currently trying to configure the maven-release-plugin to manage versioning of the builds, and to manage tagging and pushing of code to the public repository.  In my pom.xml, I have listed the <scm/> as follows:

```
<scm><connection>scm:git:http://example.com/public</connection></scm>
```

(Removing this line will cause mvn release:prepare to fail)

---

However, when calling

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

Maven calls

```
git push origin tagname
```

rather than pushing to the URL specified in the POM.

So the questions are:

1. Best practice: Should I just be tagging and committing in my private repo (origin), and pushing to public manually?
2. Can I make Maven push to the repository that I choose, rather than defaulting to origin?  I felt this was implied by the requirement of the <connection/> element in <scm/>.

Comment: (Sorry if this is a bit rambling.)

Comment: This looks like a bug with maven-release-plugin: maven pushes the tag to the local origin (git push origin tagname) and then tries to check it out from the remote specified in the pom (git pull http://example.com/public tagname).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Releasing when the scm.connection repository is different to the origin is fixed in the version 2.0 of maven-release-plugin (or the associated git plugins).  To change to this version, I added the following to my POM:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

---

Incidentally, Maven was picking up maven-release-plugin version 2.0-beta-9 as being more recent than 2.0.